# showing an error when make a post request on backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, routes

When I made a schem and also made a middleware to handle endpoint and create the schema on database it showing me error like -

[image]

this is my User.js--

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { Schema } = mongoose;


//we are creating schema here
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

//model is used to make crud operation on userSchema
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

this is my CreateUser.js---

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router;
const User = require("../models/User"); //use the schema to create user

router.post("/createuser", async (req, res) => { //POST request handler at the endpoint /createuser
    try {
        await User.create({    //create schema User
            name: "Badal",
            password: "badal123",
            email: "badal@2.com",
            location: "Jatni"
        })

        res.json({ seccess: true }); //use to send message to the json like res.send()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({ seccess: false });
    }
});

module.exports=router;
```

this is my index.js--

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoDB = require('./db')
const app = express()
const port = 5000

mongoDB();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', require("./Routes/CreateUser"));
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

I can't figure it out so Can anyone figure what exactly happened and provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `express.Router()` function inside your `CreateUser.js` file like so:

```js
const router = express.Router();
```

At the minute you are just assigning the function to a variable called `router` here:

```js
const router = express.Router;
```